# how to increase the digit part of a file name

Tags: regex, shell

I have some file in a directory like abcd1.txt, abc.txt, bc24.txt which created dynamically, I want to check the file name first, if it has a number then increase it and rename the file, if it has no any number then add number 1 to it.

```
abcd1.txt --> abcd2.txt
abc.txt   --> abc1.txt
bc24.txt  --> bc25.txt
```

I have tried to use "echo "$val"|grep -P '\d+' -o" but without any luck.

Comment: This could be pretty easy if you could use a language like python, etc.  is that an option?

Comment: What's intended output for the possibility of weird filenames like `abc1.abc.txt`, `abc1.abc1.txt` and  `abc.abc1.txt`?

Comment: To better understanding my question I have used some examples to show all the file names should be ended with a number, abc or whatever I have used in above examples are not the real file names, I have intended to show those parts are alphabetical names.

Answer (score 2):

Capture all the bits with a bash regular expression. I assume there are no digits before the digits you need to increment.

```
for f in abcd1.txt abc.txt bc24.txt; do 
    if [[ $f =~ ([^0-9]+)([0-9]*)(\.[^.]+) ]]; then 
        prefix=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        n=$(( ${BASH_REMATCH[2]-0} + 1))
        ext=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
        echo "$f => $prefix$n$ext"
    else 
        echo "can't parse filename $f"
    fi
done
```

```
abcd1.txt => abcd2.txt
abc.txt => abc1.txt
bc24.txt => bc25.txt
```

Perl is also pretty concise: find the digits before the first dot, and increment them.

```
for f in abcd1.txt abc.txt bc24.txt; do 
    perl -E '($n = $ARGV[0]) =~ s/(\d*)(?=\.)/1+$1/e; say "$ARGV[0] => $n"' "$f"
done
```